# Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE): cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame

Tags: dataframe, coerce

I am trying to make a c chart to analyse new diagnoses but I can't get past this stage. Please see code below:

Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE): cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame
Traceback:

1. qic(x = col_date, y = col_double(), data = measure1_data, chart = "c",
   .     freeze = ymd(20150201))
2. data.frame(x, y, n, notes, facets, cl, target)
3. as.data.frame(x[[i]], optional = TRUE)
4. as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE)
5. stop(gettextf("cannot coerce class %s to a data.frame", sQuote(deparse(class(x))[1L])),
   .     domain = NA)